# Android: Keep Only One Cell Highlighted - TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have been trying to create an application based of the application in the Google Play Store called Timetable. I have been struggling with an issue the past couple of days that seems simple. Basically, I created a grid with TableLayout, and I want a cell to highlight when touched, and then switch activities when touched again. However, I cannot figure out at all how to make the previously highlighted cell stop being highlighted when I select another cell. I'm trying to accomplish on a fragment inside of a navigation drawer activity.

[This is how Timetable does it. When a cell is clicked, it is highlighted. When another cell is touched, the previous cell is no longer highlighted. When a highlighted cell is tapped, or a cell that is in the same row as a highlighted cell is tapped, the activity switches.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTY32.jpg)

[This is my work. As you can see, two cells are highlighted at once and I don't want that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsyU.jpg)

I've tried changing my cells from imageviews, to imagebuttons and regular buttons, but I got the same result. I implemented a selector .xml file and the cell would either stay highlighted as I was touching it, or it would do what is shown in the screenshot of my work. It would be amazing if someone could help me with this. Do I need to consider using a GridLayout?

**Here is fragment_week.xml** (shortened to save space)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WeekFragment">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/titleRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Sun"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Mon"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Tue"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Wed"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Thu"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Fri"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" Sat"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeTable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5,6,7">


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/sevenAM"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="7:00\nAM"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />
            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/eightAM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="8:00\nAM"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/nineAM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="9:00\nAM"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tenAM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="10:00\nAM"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/elevenAM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="11:00\nAM"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />
            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/twelvePM"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="12:00\nPM"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Here is cell_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke android:width="0.05dp"  android:color="#19aaa9a9"/>
</shape>
```

**Here is cell_hightlight.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/plus" />
</layer-list>
```

**Here is WeekFragment.java**

```
package com.dmelton.classScheduler;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WeekFragment extends Fragment {

    public WeekFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_week, container, false);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        TableLayout timeTable = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timeTable);
        int count = timeTable.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View v = timeTable.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof TableRow) {
                TableRow row = (TableRow) v;
                int rowCount = row.getChildCount();
                for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
                    final View v2 = row.getChildAt(r);
                    if (v2 instanceof ImageView) {
                        final ImageView b = (ImageView) v2;

                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_highlight));
                        }
                    });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have updated your code, see below..

    public class WeekFragment extends Fragment {
    //Create a global View instance like below
    View previousView;

        public WeekFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_week, container, false);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            TableLayout timeTable = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timeTable);
            int count = timeTable.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View v = timeTable.getChildAt(i);
                if (v instanceof TableRow) {
                    TableRow row = (TableRow) v;
                    int rowCount = row.getChildCount();
                    for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
                        final View v2 = row.getChildAt(r);
                        if (v2 instanceof ImageView) {
                            final ImageView b = (ImageView) v2;

                        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_highlight));
//Check for the first time for null value
    if(previousView!=null&&previousView.equals(b)){
/*You can make cell normal here by adding b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);*/
switchActivities();
}
    previousView=null;
    //Assign new view
    previousView=b;
                            }
                        });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so what I've noticed is that when I click on a cell, it highlights. When I click on the same cell again, it stops being highlighted, and it can't be highlighted again until it I click on a new cell. Instead of the cell stop being highlighted on the second touch, how can I have that use that second touch to switch activities?